# PostgreSQL: How to split IPv6 network address into two halves

Tags: postgresql, networking, split, ipv6, inet

In PostgreSQL, I need to find a way to split IPv6 subnet into two halves, ie. calculate two IPv6 addresses that together comprise the input subnet, like this:

```
"1::/64" should give "1::/65" and "1:0:0:0:8000::/65"
```

Any idea how to do this? I have this function for IPv4, but it uses arithmetics that won't work for 128-bit numbers (net_ip is the subnet address to be split):

```
SELECT * INTO STRICT net_old FROM subnet WHERE subnet_i = _subnet_i;
mask := masklen(net_old.net_ip);
nsize := 2^(31 - mask);
_addr_new_1 := set_masklen(net_old.net_ip, mask + 1);
_addr_new_2 := set_masklen(net_old.net_ip, mask + 1) + nsize;
```

Comment: Maybe you should show those arithmetics? The first one is easy but I don't understand where the other came from.

Comment: I have added the code that works for IPv4 addresses.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found a solution, complete function in PgPL/SQL, it works on both IPv4 and IPv6:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION cidr_split_subnet(
  _subnet cidr,
  OUT _addr_low cidr,
  OUT _addr_hi cidr
) AS $$

BEGIN

_addr_low := set_masklen(_subnet, masklen(_subnet) + 1);
_addr_hi  := set_masklen(_subnet | ~netmask(_addr_low) - 1 , masklen(_addr_low));

END;

$$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

Example:

```
=> SELECT cidr_split_subnet('1::/64');
     cidr_split_subnet     
---------------------------
 (1::/65,1::8000:0:0:0/65)

=> SELECT cidr_split_subnet('192.168/16');
         cidr_split_subnet         
-----------------------------------
 (192.168.0.0/17,192.168.128.0/17)
```